# In the US Reconciliation procedure, wherein the text allows for separate bills for revenue, spending & debt for each year?

Tags: congress, parliamentary-procedure, bills

In the Reconciliation procedure, as passed in the bill here: [Congressional Budget and Impoundment Control Act of 1974](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/STATUTE-88/pdf/STATUTE-88-Pg297.pdf).

Wherein the exact text here is the interpretation that bills each for revenue, spending & debt can be passed each fiscal year? I know the procedure was supposedly written to allow for just one a year & what they're doing now in Senate is new.

I'm rather busy with many things (I really am), so I'm afraid I can't sieve through this in a timely manner. Just a point out, no need to mince it for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Politics.SE.

Comment: This question is about what procedures a law requires or permits the US congress to follow, and where in the law specific procedures are provided for. I think it belongs here on Law.

Comment: Thanks, David...

Comment: If nobody wants to point it out, then for those in the know, is it along the lines of "... a bill for revenue, spending or debt..." & the word "bill" was distributed on this 3 items, just like applying a "distributive law". As in Mathematics, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Section 310 (e) (2) of the Congressional Budget and Impoundment Control Act of 1974 (aka PUBLIC LAW 93-344-JULY 12, 1974, in this answer known as "the act") linked in the question, provides that:

> Debate in the Senate on any reconciliation bill or resolution
> reported under subsection (c), and all amendments thereto
> and debatable motions and appeals in connection therewith, shall
> be limited to not more than 20 hours

This is the provision which exempts a reconciliation bill or resolution from any filibuster.

Section 310 (c) of the act provides that:

> (c) RECONCILIATION PROCESS.—If a concurrent resolution is agreed
> to in accordance with subsection (a) containing directions to one or
> more committees to determine and recommend changes in laws, bills,
> or resolutions, and—
>
> (1) only one committee of the House or the Senate is directed to
> determine and recommend changes, that committee shall promptly
> make such determination and recommendations and report to its
> House a reconciliation bill or reconciliation resolution, or both,
> containing such recommendations; or
>
> (2) more than one committee of the House or the Senate is
> directed to determine and recommend changes, each such committee
> so directed shall promptly make such determination and
> recommendations, whether such changes are to be contained in a
> reconciliation bill or reconciliation resolution, and submit such
> recommendations to the Committee on the Budget of its House,
> which upon receiving all such recommendations, shall report to
> its House a reconciliation bill or reconciliation resolution, or both,
> carrying out all such recommendations without any substantive
> revision.
>
> For purposes of this subsection, a reconciliation resolution is a concurrent resolution directing the Clerk of the House of Representatives
> or the Secretary of the Senate, as the case may be, to make specified
> changes in bills and resolutions which have not been enrolled.

Section 310 (d) of the act provides that:

> (d) COMPLETION OF RECONCILIATION PROCESS.—Congress shall complete
> action on any reconciliation bill or reconciliation resolution
> reported under subsection (c) not later than September 25 of each
> year.

Subsections (c) and (d) together seem to authorize only a single reconciliation bill or reconciliation resolution in a given year, but that may revise or amend multiple bills and resolutions.

Section 300 of the act specifies timelines for the budget process, listing 25 September as the date by which reconciliation  should be completed. Section 305 give detailed time lines for the concurrent budget resolution proess, and limits debate on each stage.

Section 300 (b) (1) of the act provides that there can be:

> (1) a procedure under which all or certain bills and resolutions
> providing new budget authority or providing new spending
> authority described in section 401(c) (2) (C) for such fiscal year
> shall not be enrolled until the concurrent resolution required to be
> reported under section 310(a) has been agreed to, and, if a reconciliation
> bill or reconciliation resolution, or both, are required to
> be reported under section 310(c), until Congress has completed
> action on that bill or resolution, or both; and
>
> (2) any other procedure which is considered appropriate to
> carry out the purposes of this Act.

Section 311` (a) provides that:

> LEGISLATION SUBJECT TO POINT OF ORDER.—^After the
> Congress has completed action on the concurrent resolution on the
> budget required to be reported under section 310(a) for a fiscal year,
> and, if a reconciliation bill or resolution, or both, for such fiscal year
> are required to be reported under section 310(c), after that bill has
> been enacted into law or that resolution has been agreed to, it shall
> not be in order in either the House of Representatives or the Senate to
> consider any bill, resolution, or amendment providing additional new
> budget authority for such fiscal year, providing new spending authority
> described in section 401(c) (2) (C) to become effective during such
> fiscal year, or reducing revenues for such fiscal year, or any conference
> report on any such bill or resolution, if—
>
> - (1) the enactment of such bill or resolution as reported;
> - (2) the adoption and enactment of such amendment; or
> - (3) the enactment of such bill or resolution in the form recommended
>   in such conference report;
>
> would cause the appropriate level of total new budget authority or
> total budget outlays set forth in the most recently agreed to concurrent
> resolution on the budget for such fiscal year to be exceeded, or
> would cause revenues to be less than the appropriate level of revenues
> set forth in such concurrent resolution.

I cannot say that no other legislation authorizes such  procedure to be used at other times of the year. I presume that the congressional authorities have checked the relevant authorizations  and acted in accord with them, but the above sections seem to be what the question asks for.